# JDBC.Ucanaccess shows SQLException message

Tags: java, jdbc

i am new in database want to run first database program with Access but getting SQLException message "DB linking failed!"

i wrote following code with Java 8,and i have configured ucanaccess's libraries.
[Java build path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR1XN.jpg)

```
<i>

import java.sql.*;

public class Db {

public static void main(String[] args)throws SQLException
{
    Connection con =null;
    try{
    Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
    String dataSource = "jdbc:ucanaccess://D:/Database.accdb";
    con=DriverManager.getConnection(dataSource,"","");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();

    st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Table1 (ID, Name) VALUES ('4','ann')");
    st.execute("SELECT * FROM Table1");
    ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();
    while(rs.next())
    {
        System.out.println(rs.getString("ID")+rs.getString("Name"));
    }
    st.close();
    con.close();

    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("DB linking failed!");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Driver loading failed!");
    }
}

}
```

i have added "e.printStackTrace()" in the catch block as following

```
 catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Driver loading failed!");
    }
```

and got following error messages
[error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVZQA.jpg)

Comment: Could you add `e.printStackTrace();` in the `catch` block and post the output?

Comment: Print the whole exception's stacktrace in the catch block: `e.printStackTrace()` to get more info

Comment: thanks a lot! the code is working while i closed access file.